# How to delete an object from a list in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to make a to-do list in React which I can edit and delete the to-dos. I'm trying to use this function to delete a to-do, which worked on a past project.

```
function deleteTodo(id) {
const updatedTodos = [...values].filter((values) => values.id !== id);
setValues(updatedTodos);}
```

But I'm trying to use this code on this new project and I get the error 'values is not iterable'. I imagine its because the 'values' is an object, not an array, as you can see below...

```
    const [values, setValues] = useState({
    id: Date.now(),
    descricao: "",
    atividade: "",
    trabalho: true,
    pessoal: false,
  });
```

What is the best way I can delete to-dos like this? This is my code:

```
    export function App() {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({
    id: Date.now(),
    descricao: "",
    atividade: "",
    trabalho: true,
    pessoal: false,
  });

  const [atividades, setAtividades] = useState([]);

  function handleChange(event) {
    setValues({
      ...values,
      [event.target.name]: event.target.value,
      [event.target.descricao]: event.target.descricao,
    });
  }

  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    setAtividades([
      ...atividades,
      {
        id: values.id,
        nome: values.atividade,
        descricao: values.descricao,
        checkTrabalho: values.trabalho,
        checkPessoal: values.pessoal,
      },
    ]);
  }

  function deleteTodo(id) {
    const updatedTodos = [...values].filter((values) => values.id !== id);
    setValues(updatedTodos);
  }

  return (
    // ==========================================================================================
    <div className="App">
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          name="atividade"
          type="text"
          value={values.atividade}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <input
          maxLength="100"
          name="descricao"
          type="text"
          value={values.descricao}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <br />
        <input
          name="trabalho"
          id="trabalho"
          type="radio"
          checked={values.trabalho}
          onChange={() => {
            setValues({ ...values, pessoal: false, trabalho: true });
          }}
        />
        <label htmlFor="trabalho">Trabalho</label>
        <input
          name="pessoal"
          id="pessoal"
          type="radio"
          checked={values.pessoal}
          onChange={() => {
            setValues({ ...values, trabalho: false, pessoal: true });
          }}
        />
        <label htmlFor="pessoal">Pessoal</label>
        <button type="submit">Criar</button>
      </form>
      {/* ========================================================================================== */}

      {/* ========================================================================================== */}
      <div key={values.id}>
        <div>
          <h1>Trabalhos</h1>
          {atividades.map(
            (atividade) =>
              atividade.checkTrabalho === true && (
                <div>
                  Todo: {atividade.nome} <br />
                  descricao: {atividade.descricao}
                  <button onClick={deleteTodo}>deletar</button>
                </div>
              )
          )}
        </div>

        <div key={values.id}>
          <h1>Pessoal</h1>
          {atividades.map(
            (atividade) =>
              atividade.checkPessoal === true && (
                <div>
                  Todo: {atividade.nome} <br />
                  descricao: {atividade.descricao}
                  <button onClick={deleteTodo}>deletar</button>
                </div>
              )
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    // ==================================================================================================
  );
}
```

Comment: values is not an array !!

Comment: Values in the state is an object not an array so it cannot be iterated over. You also use values as the reference for the inner element which will cause some confusion.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you have created an object instead of array of objects. If you want to store multiple todo objects you should create it like:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([
{
    id: Date.now(),
    descricao: "",
    atividade: "",
    trabalho: true,
    pessoal: false,
  }
]);
```

Then you can use filter to remove items just like you are doing right now.
Or assuming you are storing your todos in `atividades`, then you should update that array of object instead of values.

```
const updatedTodos = [...atividades].filter((todo) => todo.id !== id);
```

Comment: Hey Vignesh! Thank you for your answer... Unfortunately it still doesnt work, do you have any other tips?